# How to run ARcore on a custom Snapdragon Board?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore, qualcomm

My team and I are building a custom Augmented Reality headset powered by the Snapdragon SM8250 processor ([Using the Thundercomm C865 SOM](https://www.thundercomm.com/app_en/product/1581404900209747)) We have also integrated a 9 Axis IMU and an RGBD camera to perform SLAM operations.
Since our custom device would not come under the [list of supported devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/devices) for ARcore but has all the requisite hardware, could anyone support by pointing to some resources that would help us get ARcore running on this hardware?

Comment: Did you actually manage to go further with this? Really curious

Answer (score 2):

You should contact the SOM vendor. Actually, you can contact me as I work for Thundercomm.

ARcore has to be integrated with the hardware. Usually, this requires BSP (board support package) modification and/or configuration. Similar tasks usually take more than several months.

Most certainly you wouldn't like to do it by yourself as the task requires an experience with the platform BSP. In the case with Snapdragon, all docs for HW and BSP most probably are not available freely on the Internet. You should sign an agreement with the vendor to get access to the SOC and SOM docs and to support you with the integration.